# Copying UIView using NSKeyedArchiver throws NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, nskeyedarchiver

Using this to copy `UIView`

```
UIView copyOfView = 
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:originalView]]
```

This throws the following error:

`NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException`

`[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeBoolForKey]: value for key (UIHighlighted) is not a boolean`

Comment: Any solution for this??

Answer (score 3):

If we are using `Archive/Unarchive` with `UIImageView` , I am facing error, though I fixed that highlight issue.

```
let NewView = whichView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
```

The above line will give you best solution.